# The curious case of the mysterious repeated measures effect size estimate

Tags: repeated-measures, effect-size

I am currently in the middle of a stone-cold statisical whodunnit. I need to find the name of an effect size statistic a recently departed colleague used for a project, measuring effect size of change from pre to post (i.e. it is a repeated measures effect size). The formula in the R script is:

```
delta = t*sqrt(2(1-r)/n)
```

, where `t` is the statistic from a paired *t*-test, `r` is the pearson's product-moment correlation of the pre and post scores, and `n` is the number of participants who have both pre and post scores.

Can anyone tell me the name of this effect size estimate, and perhaps a reference where it is discussed? Apart from a brief reference to it six answers down on [this Researchgate thread](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_calculate_the_effect-size_for_a_repeated_measures_t-test) I can find no other mention of it online.

Comment: I think you'll find your answer in Chapter 2 of Cohen's Statistical Power for the Behavioral Sciences, 2d ed.:  http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~brunner/oldclass/378f16/readings/CohenPower.pdf